# Infinite loop in emacs lisp when using org-table-convert-region

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been having trouble with an infinite loop in the code below. It inserts a list of items at point, comma separating them, and then converts the list to an org table.

This works when executing one at a time, but if you call from an emacs lisp function more than once, as below, then it goes into an infinite loop inserting |'s until it locks up or shows the message below.

Update it now locks up when I do (test1) as below

Can dowload a full example of the code from pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/n6iqSUXK)

I can't quite figure out what's causing this behaviour. The commented lines reflect different ways to do the same thing that cause the same bug.

```
(defun org-table-from-list(l)
  "Create an org-table from a list"
  (if (listp l)
      (let ((beg (point)))
    (insert-list l)
;   (message (format "beg end %d %d\n" beg (point)))
    (org-table-convert-region beg (point) '(4))
;   (set-mark beg)
;   (end-of-line)
;   (org-table-create-or-convert-from-region '(4))
    (forward-line))))


(defun insert-list(l)
  "insert a list L into the current buffer"
  (let ((str ""))
    (dolist (i l)
      (setf str (concat str i ",")))
    (let ((len (length str)))
      (insert (subseq str 0 (1- len))))))

(defun test1 () (interactive) (org-table-from-list '("apple" "carrot" "coke" "smile")))

(progn 
       (test1)
       (test1))
```

The error:

```
Warning (undo): Buffer `test3.txt' undo info was 12711518 bytes long.
The undo info was discarded because it exceeded `undo-outer-limit'.
```

Comment: Added it above, posted this too late at night :S

Comment: The above code works fine for me. Are you getting the error when you run "(progn (test1) (test1))" or do you only get this error when you run with "real" data? If the latter, could you provide a minimal sample data set that causes the error to occur?

Comment: Yeah this is the minimal set that causes the error. Sometimes I need to do it a few times, but I haven't isolated when it will happen. I'm on Mac OS X with emacs GNU Emacs 24.0.50.1

Comment: Works fine for me, too. Emacs 24 on Gnu/Linux though. You can write `insert-list` a lot simpler with `mapconcat`: http://pastebin.com/CeSBAmqy

Comment: You ought to test this with 23.3 and verify that the same issue occurs. If you can't replicate it in that version, then you should be sending in a bug report.

Comment: I just tested running it 60 times (instead of 2) inside the progn without any error. I'm using Aquamacs with GNU Emacs 24.0.50.3 on Mac OS X 10.7. Just thinking, have you redefined or advised any of the standard functions that are being called in the above code? Or is there anything unusual about your setup? Have you tried running it with no init files?

Comment: Works fine on Mac OS X with GNU Emacs 22.1.1 with 60 iterations as well. Definitely try it again without any init files.

Comment: Good idea I'll try it with no init files at all. @Michael thanks mapconcat is better than mine. The bit at the end of my code is actually a convoluted way to dump the final comma. I was thinking of writing a dolist-cond macro that executes a different body each loop step depending on conditions such as how many items left, but that's for another day.

Comment: @Michael, oh I see. mapconcat inserts between the characters, perfect!

Comment: I cannot replicate this at all after rebooting my macbook. I think this could have been gremlins.

Comment: The OP admits that it is a non-problem: unreproducible.